# TF Lookup working with ros::Time(0) but not ros::Time::now()?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First off, the code:

```
tf::TransformListener listener;
tf::StampedTransform transform;
try {
  ros::Time now = ros::Time::now(); //The changing code

  ROS_INFO("Waiting for transform...");
  listener.waitForTransform("/base_footprint", "/map",
                          now, ros::Duration(5.0));

  ROS_INFO("Looking up transform...");
  listener.lookupTransform("/base_footprint", "/map",
                           now, transform);
}
catch(tf::TransformException ex) {
  ROS_ERROR("%s", ex.what());
  return 1;
}
```

This code is supposed to lookup the current position of the robot. However, when I run the code as is, I get the error:

```
[ INFO] [1373921514.306158805]: Waiting for transform...
[ INFO] [1373921514.316335148, 908.830000000]: Looking up transform...
[ERROR] [1373921514.316529725, 908.830000000]: Frame id /base_footprint does not exist! Frames (1):
```

If I change the marked Time to ros::Time(0), as so:

```
ros::Time now = ros::Time(0);
```

the code works fine. Why? What difference does it make?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67384/tf-lookup-working-with-ros::time(0)-but-not-ros::time::now()?/) by [cmdli](https://answers.ros.org/users/5422/cmdli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-07-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not an answer, but hopefully a pointer to an answer:

- [This tutorial on tf and time](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/tf%20and%20Time%20(C%2B%2B%29)
  explains the difference between `ros::Time(0)` and `ros::Time::now()`
- These [various command-line tools for debugging tf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#Command-line_Tools) may also be useful for figuring out what's going on in your system.

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2